# Issues with IE11 and SVG's

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I'm having trouble getting an SVG icon to render in IE11. This is especially tricky since I can't reproduce this issue in my own dev environments so I can't really debug this on my own. I'm hoping maybe someone with more experience working with SVG's and IE11 can point out a gotcha that I'm missing somewhere in the SVG markup. It's also part of an angular ap

Here's the SVG markup that I'm trying to render:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="18" viewBox="0 0 20 18">
   <defs>
       <path id="a" d="M0 18V0h20v18z"/>
   </defs>
   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
       <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
           <use xlink:href="#a"/>
       </mask>
       <path fill="#626669" d="M16.25 18h-15c-1 0-1.625-1.157-1-2.057l3.5-4.757V3.857C3.75 1.671 5.375 0 7.5 0h8.75C18.375 0 20 1.671 20 3.857v10.286C20 16.329 18.375 18 16.25 18zm-12.5-2.571h12.5c.75 0 1.25-.515 1.25-1.286V3.857c0-.771-.5-1.286-1.25-1.286H7.5c-.75 0-1.25.515-1.25 1.286v7.714c0 .258-.125.515-.25.772l-2.25 3.086z" mask="url(#b)"/>
       <path fill="#626669" d="M8.75 5.143H15v2.571H8.75zM8.75 10.286H15v2.571H8.75z" mask="url(#b)"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Any kind of help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly happens on IE11?

Comment: The icon doesn't appear at all.